# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException with non existing class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a wird problem with Spring. I'm working on a small mvc application and after some work I'm faceing such a problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'userServiceImpl' for bean class [com.(...).servlet3.UserServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.(...).service.UserServiceImpl]
```

This exception looks like sefl-explain but there is one thing wird: I do not have such class as [com.(...).servlet3.UserServiceImpl]. I used to have, but moved to another package. My structure looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

Does anyone has faced such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check get and set method in bean for path bean definition or path name seems duplicate.